# Memory allocation in Yarn Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am having this error in pyspark (Amazon EMR), my file is about 2G. How can I do to change the allocation?

Thanks

In tried to increase the size of the cluster, at some stages I still have the problem

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (8192),
>   overhead (1536 MB), and PySpark memory (0 MB) is above the max
>   threshold (5760 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of
>   'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or
>   'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.

Answer (score -1):

When you submit your job to Apache Spark you can add some parameters to your script to customize the memory example below. 
Those parameters will overwrite the default configuration

Example

```
"--deploy-mode": "cluster",
"--num-executors": 60,
"--executor-memory": "16g",
"--executor-cores": 5,
"--driver-memory": "16g",
"--conf": {"spark.driver.maxResultSize": "2g"}
```

Comment: Thanks a  mil! I will try that!